# XML:Picking specific characters from a string

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following 3 xml files:

0002.xml

ex32002.xml

flt-03-3220-2002.xml

Now I need to pick only the last two characters before `.xml`, i.e. in all the 3 cases `02`

I am trying to achieve this using `base-uri()` and `substring` function. But I am stuck. Tried using `string-length` function but could'nt do it as the length of filename varies. Need help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a sequence of those file names you can use `for $fname in ('0002.xml', 'ex32002.xml', 'flt-03-3220-2002.xml')
return substring($fname, string-length($fname) - 5, 2)` to get a sequence of strings `('02', '02', '02')` so using `substring` computed from the back should do.

Comment: Got it. Had some confusion with string-length. Thanks.